# How to solve the problem with social network authentication that works through next-auth and prisma?

Tags: node.js, authentication, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I have a problem with authorization through social networks, to be precise through - github. In my application, I use two social networks through which it is possible to log in: google, github. As for databases, I use mongoDB in this project. In the case of authorization through google, everything is successful, but when you authorize using github, the following error occurs. I would be grateful if someone could help.

```
[next-auth][debug][adapter_getUserByAccount] { args: [ { providerAccountId: '110691813', provider: 'github' } ] }
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getUserByAccount] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getuserbyaccount
Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    provider_providerAccountId: {
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      providerAccountId: "110691813",
      provider: "github"
    },
?   id?: String,
?   provider_providerACcountId?: AccountProviderProviderACcountIdCompoundUniqueInput,
?   AND?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],
?   OR?: AccountWhereInput[],
?   NOT?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],
?   userId?: StringFilter | String,
?   type?: StringFilter | String,
?   provider?: StringFilter | String,
?   providerACcountId?: StringFilter | String,
?   refresh_token?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
?   access_token?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
?   expires_at?: IntNullableFilter | Int | Null,
?   token_type?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
?   scope?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
?   id_token?: StringFilter | String,
?   session_state?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
?   user?: UserRelationFilter | UserWhereInput
  },
  select: {
    user: true
  }
}
Unknown argument `provider_providerAccountId`. Did you mean `provider_providerACcountId`? Available options are marked with ?. {
  message: '\n' +
    'Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:\n' +
    '\n' +
    '{\n' +
    '  where: {\n' +
    '    provider_providerAccountId: {\n' +
    '    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n' +
    '      providerAccountId: "110691813",\n' +
    '      provider: "github"\n' +
    '    },\n' +
    '?   id?: String,\n' +
    '?   provider_providerACcountId?: AccountProviderProviderACcountIdCompoundUniqueInput,\n' +
    '?   AND?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],\n' +
    '?   OR?: AccountWhereInput[],\n' +
    '?   NOT?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],\n' +
    '?   userId?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '?   type?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '?   provider?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '?   providerACcountId?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '?   refresh_token?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '?   access_token?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '?   expires_at?: IntNullableFilter | Int | Null,\n' +
    '?   token_type?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '?   scope?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '?   id_token?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '?   session_state?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '?   user?: UserRelationFilter | UserWhereInput\n' +
    '  },\n' +
    '  select: {\n' +
    '    user: true\n' +
    '  }\n' +
    '}\n' +
    '\n' +
Unknown argument `provider_providerAccountId`. Did you mean `provider_providerACcountId`? Available options are marked with ?.
    at ti (C:Coding\project\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:118:5888)
    at si.handleRequestError (C:Coding\project\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:125:6473)
    at si.handleAndLogRequestError (C:Coding\project\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:125:6151)        
    at si.request (C:Coding\project\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:125:5859)
    at async l (C:Coding\project\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:130:10025)
    at async getUserByAccount (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:222:29) :beginner: :100: {
name: 'GetUserByAccountError',
  code: undefined
}
```

I tried to solve the problem on my own, looked for various articles related to this, but did not find a solution.